# How to fix "e.preventDefault is not a function" error in react js authentication?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, firebase-authentication, event-handling

I need to make authentication (SignUp, SignIn pages). When I fill email and password fields to create a user on the SignUp page, after pressing Register button I get the "e.preventDefault is not a function" error. It seems there's an issue in the handleSubmit logic.

I have tried to change e to event, didn't work, had the same error "event.preventDefault is not a function". Also moved e.preventDefault() to Form element, didn't work. My code is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";
import { UserAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import "../sass/main.scss";

const Signup = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const { createUser } = UserAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    try {
      await form.validateFields();
      await createUser(email, password);

      console.log("User created successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="loginFormContainer">
      <div className="loginForm">
        <header className="loginFormTitle">
          <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "550" }}>Create a new account</h3>
        </header>
        <p style={{ paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
          Already have an account? <Link to="/">Sign in.</Link>
        </p>
        <Form form={form} onFinish={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Item
            name="email"
            label="E-mail"
            rules={[
              {
                type: "email",
                message: "The input is not valid E-mail!",
              },
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input your E-mail!",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input your password!",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input.Password
              onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Register
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Comment: See https://ant.design/components/form#api, the parameter passed in `onFinish` callback is form value, not event.

Answer (score 0):

since you're using `antd` library, the event is different from regular HTML events. I see you aren't so familair with it so I would prefer to remove the `onFinish` event from the `Form` tag and give the handler to the register button via the `onClick` attribute or just use plain HTML form and give the nadler to the form via `onSubmit` attribute.